# How do I define a morphism of sheaves $G \mapsto f_{\ast}(f^{-1}G)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous map of topological spaces, and $G$ a sheaf on $Y$.  I know that the association $G \mapsto f^{-1}G$, and $F \mapsto f_{\ast}F$ are covariant functors from the category of sheaves on $Y$ to the category of sheaves on $X$, and back again.  Hence the composition $G \mapsto f^{-1}G \mapsto f_{\ast}f^{-1}G$ is a covariant functor from from the category of sheaves on $Y$ to itself.  I'm having trouble seeing why there is a natural morphism of sheaves $$G \mapsto f_{\ast}(f^{-1}G)$$ In other words, why there is a natural transformation from the identity functor $Sh_Y \rightarrow Sh_Y$ to the functor $Sh_Y \rightarrow Sh_Y$ given by $G \mapsto f_{\ast}(f^{-1}G)$.  Maybe I'm missing something because I'm very rusty on adjoints.  I just don't have any concrete description of $f^{-1}G$, so I don't know how to define a homomorphism $G(V) \rightarrow f_{\ast}(f^{-1}G))(V) = f^{-1}G(f^{-1}V)$.

Comment: You should study the nature of the adjoint pairing between $f_*$ and $f^{-1}$. Once you understand how to use it to transpose maps, then try transposing the identity map on $f^{-1} G$. You'll get a map $G \to f_* (f^{-1} G)$. This is the natural map you're looking for.

Comment: Could you define such a map if we used the "presheaf $f^{-1}$" instead?